# No module named bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Tried to run bokeh from the command window using

```
 bokeh serve --show myapp/  
-m bokeh serve --show myapp.py
```

Keeping getting an error about 'bokeh' is not recognized as an internal or external command or No module named bokeh. Below are my settings.

```
 bokeh in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.4.0)
 packaging>=16.8 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bokeh) (19.2)
 PyYAML>=3.10 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bokeh) (5.1.2)
 tornado>=4.3 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bokeh) (6.0.3)
 numpy>=1.7.1 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bokeh) (1.17.4)
 Jinja2>=2.7 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bokeh) (2.10.3)
 python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bokeh) (2.8.1)
 six>=1.5.2 in c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from bokeh) (1.13.0)
 pillow>=4.0 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bokeh) (6.2.1)
 pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->bokeh) (2.4.5)
 MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.7->bokeh) (1.1.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the Python executable you are running is not the one in your Anaconda env. E.g. perhaps you are running a system built-in Python, or some other installed Python version, because it is first on your PATH. Typically conda environments need to be "activated" which will make the necessary changes to put that specific Python (and I believe on Windows, its associated `Scripts` directory) at the front of your path.

Comment: Not sure what to do to fix it. I tried reinstalling it and some other things.

Comment: Why you run python by itself does it say "Anaconda, Inc." ? If not, you are running some other Python. You would need to update your PATH to point at the Anaconda installation. Alternatively, I think Anaconda ships with an "Anaconda Shell" on Windows. That defaults to the one you want and is probably in the Start Menu.

Comment: I just reinstalled everything from anaconda and set the path from there. It works now. Thanks